# Fading Divs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, fadeout, effects

Hey Guys I am having trouble fading out a Div in my HTML document. I am able to use the same function reversed and am able to fade the divs in as required but not out. Any ideas?

Here is the JavaScript function:

```
function fadeOut(node, duration) {
    var increments = 100;
    var increment_value = 1/increments;
    var interval = duration/increments;
    var opacity = 1;

    var repeater = setInterval( function() {
        if (opacity > 0) {
            opacity = opacity - increment_value;
            node.style.opacity = opacity;
        } else {
            clearInterval(repeater);
        }
    }, interval);
}
```

Comment: Whats the code for your fadeIn which is working. Are you sure it's being stopped? I'd say it's quite likely your fadeIn interval is still going and the 2 events are just cancelling each other out. Can you make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: BTW, there's no need to use extra variable for opacity value. And don't forget to set opacity equals zero at last iteration.

Comment: Why not use `jQuery fadeIn()`?

Comment: [seems to be working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/emrLmfvn/).

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi are you suggesting to use a huge library for a tiny piece of code? i'd ask why not use css transition instead...

Answer (score 2):

You can use css-transitions to fade in/out (in other words: leave the actual fading to the browser):

Let's have an element

```
<div id="fader"> fader
  <div data-dofade="1">Let us fade in/out</div>
</div>
```

For this element the following css

```
#fader div {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all ease-in 1s 0s;
}

#fader div.fadeout {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all ease-out 1s 0s;
}
```

Now you can use this handler to fade the div within div#fader in or out:

```
document.querySelector('#fader').addEventListener(
        'click',  
        function(e){
          var fadeEl =  this.querySelector('[data-dofade]');
          fadeEl.className = /fadeout/i.test(fadeEl.className)  ? '' : 'fadeout';
        }
);
```

Feel free to fiddle around with it in this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/6b6vbxnz/) (contains a scripted fader too).

See also: [css transition (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)